# How to capture document.ready or window.load events in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, dom, addeventlistener, gatsby

I am relatively new to the **Gatbsy** framework and I am trying to figure out a way to **toggle classes** on some elements on `DOMContentLoaded` or on `window.load`, to animate them as soon as the user can see the screen.

This is what I did until now however it doesn't seem very appropriate:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") return
  window.addEventListener("load", this.myEventHandler)
  // or
  if (typeof document === "undefined") return
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.myEventHandler)
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should add these event listeners in the `gatsby-browser.js`:

```
// gatsby-browser.js
// ES6
export const onClientEntry = () => {
  window.onload = () => { /* do stuff */ }
}

// or commonjs
exports.onClientEntry = () => {
  window.onload = () => { /* do stuff */ }
}
```

You don't have to check for `window` there because this file is only run on the client side. Here's the [full list of available hooks](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onClientEntry).

also AFAIK `document` doesn't have a `ready` event, it's a `jQuery` thing. You might be interested in [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event), though there's some small different between that and jQuery's ready IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

> This is what I did until now however it doesn't seem very appropriate:

This is perfectly legitimate code imho:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  window.addEventListener("load", this.myEventHandler);
  ...
```

EDIT

Thinking about this, by the time componentDidMount has run, window "load" and document "ready" will already have fired... so it is a bit pointless.

https://codesandbox.io/s/n43z5x00j4

You can just use componentDidMount to check that the DOM has loaded and not bother with the other two events.

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like the componentDidMount event is fired before the document is rendered

Comment: I think it does depend on whether you have large multimedia assets to load - and at what point you load the js script